# Context broker is not started: parameter header not recogined

Tags: fiware-orion

I am deploying contextbroker and when I use "-multiservice header"
 as contextBroker_extra_ops option, the contextBroker is not started and not further information is obtained. Could you help me?

I am using contextBroker version 0.15.0

```
contextBroker -port 9999 -logDir /var/log/contextBroker -pidpath /var/log/contextBroker/contextBroker.pid -dbhost 127.0.0.1:27017 -db testdb1 -multiservice header
log directory: '/var/log/contextBroker'

DEBUG@12:59:56  paConfig.cpp[892]: setting trace levels to '0-255'
DEBUG@12:59:56  paConfig.cpp[893]: Leaving function paConfigActions
parameter 'header' not recognized
```

Using /etc/init.d/contextBroker I got a failure

```
/etc/init.d/contextBroker start
Starting...
contextBroker is stopped
Starting contextBroker...                         cat: /var/log/contextBroker/contextBroker.pid: No such file or directory
pidfile not found                                          [FAILED]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `-multiservice` CLI parameter changed between version 0.14.1 and 0.15.0. From 0.15.0 changelog:

```
# rpm -q --changelog contextBroker
* mié oct 01 2014 Fermin Galan <fermin@tid.es> 0.15.0-1 (FIWARE-3.5.3-1)
...
- Fix: made the broker not support URL-based multiservice (tenants) anymore (Issue #522)
- Fix: removed all the code related to URL-tenants (Issue #522)
...
```

Just replacing `-multiservice header` by `-multiheader` should solve the problem.